# auth context not updating react / react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-context

For some reason the `AuthContext` isn't updating. I have logged throughout the process but no idea why the user isn't being set. My code looks as follows:

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App() {
  const { user, setUser } = useAuth();

  console.log(user)  -> user is null here

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          {user?.session_token ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="BottomTabNavigator"
                component={BottomTabNavigator}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**useAuth.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSecureStore } from "./useSecureStore";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/authContext";

export const useAuth = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { getItem, setItem, removeItem } = useSecureStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const user = await getItem("user");
      if (user) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(user));
      }
    };

    getUser();
  }, []);

  const login = (user: AuthUser) => {
    setUser(user);
    setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    removeItem("user");
  };

  return { user, setUser, login, logout };
};
```

**useSecureStore.tsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

export const useSecureStore = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const setItem = async (key: string, value: string) => {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    setValue(value);
  };

  const getItem = async (key: string) => {
    const value = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    setValue(value);
    return value;
  };

  const removeItem = async (key: string) => {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
    setValue(null);
  };

  return { value, setItem, getItem, removeItem };
};
```

**authContext.ts**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface AuthContext {
  user: AuthUser | null;
  setUser: (user: AuthUser | null) => void;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContext>({
  user: null,
  setUser: () => {},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the context before providing it.
It's a circular dependency issue.

-> `useAuth` is called on App to get `user` and `setUser` from the `AuthContext` -> `user` and `setUser` are used to provide the `AuthContext` through the `AuthProvider`.

The rule of thumb is: You can only use `useContext` on components wrapped by the `Context.Provider`, as if you call it before it, they won't be found (this is why it's still being found as null).

To solve it, you got to:

- Break the cyclical path, where you don't use `useContext` to get the initial values of `user` and `setUser` you'll use on your Context Provider (using `useState` instead).

Below you can find 2 solutions for your issue, the simplest one (changing only one line of code) and my suggestion, which uses an abstraction I like to use when creating Contexts.

## Simplest fix

In case you want to change the fewer lines of code as possible, here is a fix:

useAuth.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSecureStore } from "./useSecureStore";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/authContext";

export const useAuth = () => {
  // Here's where you created the circular dependency when using `useContext`
  const { user, setUser } = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);
  const { getItem, setItem, removeItem } = useSecureStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const user = await getItem("user");
      if (user) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(user));
      }
    };

    getUser();
  }, []);

  const login = (user: AuthUser) => {
    setUser(user);
    setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    removeItem("user");
  };

  return { user, setUser, login, logout };
};
```

## Best (suggested) solution

Here is a suggestion on how I'd implement it and how I generally use React Context, abstracting the Provider logic to a single file.
The core changes are:

1. Merge `useAuth` and `authContext` files into one
2. Separate the `StackNavigator` logic into a single component to use `useAuth`. When `useAuth` is called from the context of this component, given it's below the `Provider` in the tree, `user` will be updated correctly for it.
3. Update `App` to reflect those changes

And the final files would be something like the below (since you didn't add all files, I might have some code mistakes here, so test to ensure I didn't miswrite something):
IMPORTANT: If you call `useAuth` anywhere before the `AuthContextProvider`, your `user` will still become null, what would happen when calling it from `App` or `NavigationContainer` components.

App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <StackNavigator />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

useAuthContext.tsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { useSecureStore } from "./useSecureStore";


interface IAuthContext {
  user: AuthUser | null;
  setUser(user: AuthUser | null): void;
  login(user: AuthUser): void
  logout(): void
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext | undefined>(undefined)

export const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, setUser } = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);
  const { getItem, setItem, removeItem } = useSecureStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const user = await getItem("user");
      if (user) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(user));
      }
    };

    getUser();
  }, []);

  const login = (user: AuthUser) => {
    setUser(user);
    setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    removeItem("user");
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user, setUser, login, logout
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext)
  if (context === undefined)
    throw new Error('useAuthContext should be used within a AuthContextProvider ')

  return context
}
```

StackNavigator.tsx

```
export default function StackNavigator() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const isUserSignedIn = !!user?.session_token

  const signedInUserScreen = (
    <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabNavigator" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
  )

  const signedOutUserScreen = (
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
  )
  const screenToDisplay = isUserSignedIn
    ? signedInUserScreen
    : signedOutUserScreen

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      {screenToDisplay}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

PS: If the `Stack.Screen`'s are expensive to compute / render or you want to avoid rendering both, you could wrap them in a function so only one is rendered at any given moment.